# Getting value from TCL variable

Tags: tcl

I have a line in TCL:

```
set val A_$Name*10
```

where

```
$Name = "B"
```

When I do:

```
puts $val
```

I get

```
"A_B*10"
```

How can I get the actual value of A_B * 10?
Thanks

Comment: You have a variable named `A_B*10`?

Comment: Hi, my variable name is A_B. I want to multiply the value of the variable by 10.

Comment: In addition to Chris's answer, it's better to use an array or dict instead of trying to build variable names at runtime. `set a($name) 2; puts [expr {$a(B) * 10}]` for example.

Answer (score 3):

You can't do math operators in the `set` assignment like that.  Use the `expr` command to do that.

You are also doing a double substitution.  First from Name to B, second from A_B to its value.   Using `set` with one argument, to get the value of the var name, is a nice way to do double substitution.

```
set A_B 10
set Name B

set val [expr [set A_$Name] * 10]    --> 100
```

Comment: If you can do `set A(B) 10` instead, you can then do `expr {$A($B) * 10}` and that works. Almost all cases of double substitution should become arrays (or something with `upvar` in the remaining cases).

Comment: And _brace your expressions!_ Always do that unless you have an _expression_ in a variable/returned from a command.